# design pattern for getMessage

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have serial device that transmits several types of messages in answer. Each message header represents message type. Each message type has it's set of fields. I never know which message type I will get.

In my code each message type represents class. What is the best way to return message with the help of getMessage function? I can return message interface or parent message class that will hold concrete message. But is it nice design at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `interface` to summarize several `classes` of a similar structure is a good design.

I guess you have a structure like:

```
public interface Message {
     public String getType();
}
```

and then several implemenations like

```
public class FooMessage implements Message {
    public String getType() { return "Foo"; }
    public String getFooField() { return fooField; }
    /* ... */
}
```

so your `getMessage()` method looks like:

```
public Message getMessage() {
    Message message = /* get the next message */;
    return message;
}
```

That would be a good approach for that problem.

Comment: Yes, that I was thought about. I don't like only that fact that do instanceOf on getMessage() return and make typecast.

Comment: @user1501700 Well, if you don't know what will come than there is not so much that you can do.